# How do I map a table with objects of terms to different string descriptions?

Tags: sql, pandas, database, sqlite, mapping

I am trying to use a table that has headers that correspond to categorizations to descriptions for products

Table1

| ID | Description |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Wow what a nice car |
| 2 | That automobile is fabulous |
| 3 | When will they serve us dessert? |
| 4 | When is Jim's ride showing up? |
| 5 | What do I have to do to get a decent cookie around here! |
| 6 | Bury me with a chocolate sundae. |

CategoryTable

| Dessert | Cars | Coffee |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Candy | Car | Cold Brew |
| Cake | Automobile | Starbucks |
| Chocolate | Driving | Mug |
| Cookie | Ride |  |
| sundae | Park |  |
| Dessert | Wheels |  |

| ID | Description | Result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Wow what a nice car | Car |
| 2 | That automobile rocks | Car |
| 3 | When's Dessert? | Dessert |
| 4 | Where is Jim's ride? | Car |
| 5 | Gimme the Cookie! | Dessert |
| 6 | Starbucks is popular. | Coffee |

I am happy to use Python, SQL or Excel to figure this all out thanks in advance!

Comment: How do you know to which category belongs each description?

Comment: How many rows your df has?

Comment: The category belongs to the description if one of the values in the category column is in the description string, there are 600,000 rows in the df ,I can get it smaller to be 6,000 if needed but would prefer not to

Comment: The table is not formatted correctly, but "Automobile" is in the  "Car"  column in Table 2, if there is more than 1 category in a description, ideally it would return the names of all matching categories, or it would say "Multiple Categories"

Comment: Here is the data formatted better in Google Sheets https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rU_Vt8hZH9pJCdrRq_JiDseaVGclYQsxPmTtVLeglM0/edit#gid=1215060968

Comment: Using supervised Machine Learning seems like too complex of a solution to me, but I can try it out

Comment: Let me first provide you a partial answer and see what percent will have labels.

Answer (score 0):

Note that I just separated tags and description tables in different sheets.

Sheet5:

[image]

Sheet1:

[image]

Use:

```
data = pd.read_excel('Example Data Set.xlsx', sheet_name='Sheet5')

tags = pd.read_excel('Example Data Set.xlsx', sheet_name='Sheet1')
tags_str = '|'.join([x.lower() for x in tags.fillna('_').values.flatten()])
temp = data['Description'].str.lower().str.extract(f"( {tags_str} )")
def tag2cat(tag):
    for col in tags.columns:
        if tag.values[0] in tags[col].str.lower().values:
            return col

temp.apply(tag2cat, axis = 1)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Hi - this doesn't answer the problem. I need it to return the header name, not the term that it found in the description.

Comment: That works now?

Comment: Hi - this is what I am looking for! Beause there are so many rows, i am looking for it to be output in to another CSV or to overwrite the data sheet

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
pattern = '|'.join([f"(?P<{c}>{'|'.join(df2[c].str.lower().dropna())})"
                        for c in df2])

df1['Result'] = (df1['Description']
                   .str.lower().str.extractall(pattern)
                   .stack().reset_index(level=2).groupby(level=0)['level_2']
                   .apply(lambda x: ', '.join(set(x))))
```

Output:

```
>>> df1
   ID                                        Description                 Result
0   1                                Wow what a nice car                   Cars
1   2                        That automobile is fabulous                   Cars
2   3                   When will they serve us dessert?                Dessert
3   4                     When is Jim's ride showing up?                   Cars
4   5  What do I have to do to get a decent cookie ar...                Dessert
5   6                   Bury me with a chocolate sundae.                Dessert
```

It works if you have multiple match. Tags will be comma separated.

Comment: Hi - this looks good but I don't understand how the different datasets map to the listing, like the df1 and pattern? How is the data being pulled in?